# OAuth 2.0 not working on Local IIS

Tags: c#, iis, oauth, thinktecture-ident-server

I was doing OAuth 2.0 authentication for my app (client credentials flow). I have Identity Server, ASP.NET Web Api as an app to which I'm authenticating and console app as a client app.

Everything works fine when my Web Api is hosted on IIS Express. When I changed it to Local IIS, it doesn't work. On IIS Express I'm getting `ClaimsIdentity` as request principal, but on Local IIS I'm getting `WindowsIdentity`, which doesn't have claims.

I'm using `Thinktecture` libs for OAuth and `Owin` for configuration. This is how my Startup class looks like:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"],
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "api" }
        });
    }
}
```

This is how I check principal identity:

```
var claims = ((ClaimsIdentity)p.Identity).Claims;
        var roleClaim = claims.Where(i => i.Type == "client_role").FirstOrDefault();
if (roleClaim == null)
{
   return null;
}
```

Ofcourse I'm returing null, when I'm on Local IIS, because this Identity doesn't have any claim.

Why my app changes behavior when I'm changing IIS? I was trying to change something in IIS configuration, but to be honest I was doing this rather blindly.

Does anybody know what is causing problem here?

EDIT:
I'll show also how I'm getting token and sending requests, maybe this is causing the problem.

```
private static TokenResponse GetToken()
{
    var client = new OAuth2Client(new Uri(IdentityServerUri), clientId,clientScope);
    return client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("scope").Result;
 }
```

Main function:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var tokenResponse = GetToken();
client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
var result = client.GetStringAsync(requestUri).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

In IIS check that you have the authentication set to none. It sounds like the windows auth module is enabled. try this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837139)